# How do i get the variable into the javascript tag?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have managed to get part of this code working.

The variables will echo without problem but as soon as I try and put them into the javascript tag they stop working.

What am I doing wrong??

```
    <?php
$id_1 = $_GET['id'];
$tag_id = "tag_id";
$Activity_Tag_String = "Activity_Tag_String";
$group_tag_string = "group_tag_string";

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT $tag_id, $Activity_Tag_String, $group_tag_string, advertiser_id FROM tbl_tags WHERE advertiser_id = '$id_1'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);


?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Mate Example</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var branch = window.location.href;

var axel = Math.random() + "";
var a = axel * 10000000000000;
document.write('<iframe src="http://fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=<?php $tag_id?>;type=<?php $Activity_Tag_String?>;cat=<?php $group_tag_string?>;u1='';ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to `<?php echo $var;?>`

Comment: The MySQL tags and code are really irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php $tag_id?>
```

should be

```
<?= $tag_id ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $tag_id ?>
```

Your version is simply doing the PHP equivalent of:

```
$tag_id;
```

which is a do-nothing statement. You need to actually **echo** that variable's contents.

As well, note that your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you should fix that before you do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

for js script part try:

```
<?php echo $variable;?>
```

or in short

```
<?=$var?>
```